# Custom sub-select requests and where clauses with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to list the content of a table using sub-selects and select only the one that match my WHERE clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `torrentItem` as ti,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE `torrentItem` = ti AND `voteType` = 0) AS `badVotes`, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE `torrentItem` = ti AND `voteType` = 1) AS `goodVotes`,
(SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,(SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM votes WHERE `torrentItem` = ti),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AS `weeksSinceLastVote`
FROM `votes` 
WHERE (`badVotes` > 1 AND `goodVotes` = 0 AND `weeksSinceLastVote` > 1);
```

It's not working : MySQL tells me that I can't just use `badVotes` or `goodVotes` in the `WHERE` clause : 
`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'badVotes' in 'where clause'`

Can you explain me why ? And how to do it ?

Comment: you can not use alias in where clause... try using `having`

Comment: Can you detail how tu use having ?

Comment: just change `where` to `having`

Comment: Okay, it's working, can you add it as an answer so I can give you the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row in your table each subquery is executed. Performance nightmare :)
You can rewrite your query as

```
SELECT `torrentItem` as ti,
SUM(`voteType` = 0) AS `badVotes`, 
SUM(`voteType` = 1) AS `goodVotes`,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, MAX(`date`), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS `weeksSinceLastVote`
FROM `votes` 
GROUP BY ti
HAVING (`badVotes` > 1 AND `goodVotes` = 0 AND `weeksSinceLastVote` > 1);
```

This will run much, much better than your subqueries.

The reason why you can't use an alias in the `where` clause is the order in which a query is interpreted.

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. ORDER BY
6. SELECT

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the column alias on where clause.

However you can use `having` clause for the same.

Check more details here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html